# What's the best way to make Rails 3 / Active Record associations for classes of a simple point of sale program?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 5 classes that are part of a point of sales program:
Customer, Technician, Order, Ticket, Service

Each Order has one customer and many tickets.  Each Ticket has on technician and many services.

How should I make the associations so that I can do the following lookup:
    customer.order.find_by_date(10/20/2010).service.technician.name

This is what I am planning:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :orders
  has_many :tickets, :through => :orders
  has_many :technicians, :through => :tickets
end  

class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
  belongs_to :service
end  

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :technicians  
  belongs_to :ticket
end  

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  has_many :technicians, :through => :services      
end  

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :services, :through => tickets
  has_many :technicians, :through => services

  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Comment: With your current layout you won't be able to do your lookup as a service has_many technicians. Should this be has_one technician or is it possible to have multiple technicians working on a service?

Comment: multiple technicians can perform the same service; however, each ticket has only one technician performing one or more services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between customer and order is one-to-many. And the relationship between order and service is also one-to-many. Therefore you cannot do:

```
customer.order.find_by_date('10/20/2010').service.technician.name
```

It should be:

```
customer.orders.find_by_date('10/20/2010').services.each do |service|
  service.technician.name
end
```

It's a similar problem as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003744/active-record-rails-3-associations-not-working-properly).