# Active Record Rails 3 associations not working properly

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following classes with associations:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :tickets, :through => :orders
  has_many :technicians, :through => :ticket
  has_many :services, :through => :ticket
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :technicians, :through => :tickets
  has_many :services, :through => :tickets
end  

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :technicians, :through => :tickets
  has_many :orders, :through => :tickets
end  

class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, :order => 'created_at DESC'
  has_many :services, :through => :tickets
  has_many :orders, :through => :tickets
end  

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :technician
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I can do:
    technician.tickets.service.price

But I can't do:
    customer.orders.technician.name
    customer.orders.last.tickets.technician.name

How do I go from customer to technician or service?

Comment: Groovy/Grails can do that :-) Via the *-operator, which broadcasts a method invocation on each item in a collection. Super nifty, along with nil delegation via `?` the first thing I missed when moving to Rails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot call a property on a collection of objects.

```
customer.orders.technician.name
```

Here you have a collection of `orders`. Each `order` could have a different `technician`. That's why you cannot call `technician` on a collection.

Solution: call `technician` on each `order` object:

```
customer.orders.each do |order|
  order.technician.name
end
```

Same goes for your second example. Instead of:

```
customer.orders.last.tickets.technician.name
```

Use:

```
customer.orders.last.tickets.each do |ticket|
  ticket.technician.name
end
```